# Mouse click trouble with the use of PyAutoGUI on a remote desktop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I have some boring repetetive tasks at work.
I use an remote desktop so they can run at night and so on.

But i have a problem with mouse clicks on the remote desktop. When i am connected through my laptop the script works fine. But when i am not connected i get this error message from PyAutoGUI:
'PyAutoGUI fail-safe triggered from mouse moving to a corner of the screen'

This error comes when the mouse is not visible on the screen.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the owner, this is not supported. He gathered all the issues at the repo related to this subject [here](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/133). There is even an [issue](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/34) opened that describes a very similar situation.

However, this [comment](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/34#issuecomment-229349166) describes a hack that could solve this problem. I haven't tried myself, but it looks promising. It says:

> Use a remote desktop client that allows you to keep outputting the
>   display, even if you minimise the window/close your PC. I used
>   terminals (https://github.com/Terminals-Origin/Terminals - not affiliated with them
>   at all just recommending as it solved this issue for me).You can set
>   this up to persist the display, and your code should then run fine.

Note: I've updated the link provided.